# Can I use Firebase as offline NoSQL database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to give a choice to users of my app: sync or not to sync their data.

As Firebase provides whole NoSQL-db, can I use it without authentification and synchronization? Can I use Firebase as offline NoSQL database without any auth request to the cloud?

Comment: "The Firebase Database is primarily a cloud-hosted database, but it continues to work if your device is without network for short to medium intervals. It is not an offline-first database. If that is what you need, you might want to look for a better fit." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796641/firebase-true-offline-capabilities, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778680/firebase-offline-capabilities-as-cache and probably a few more

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I want to use it as offline database while user not authenticated at the first time. As I understand, I must use local database, like Realm or SQLite and notify Firebase DB when local data changed to sync it with cloud. And notify local database when specific Firebase's ValueEventListener called.

Comment: Using Firebase Authentication requires (at least an initial) network connection. You can [use Firebase Database without authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules), although I would recommend at the very least using [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) to track what session made changes.